How to force non-optional type (for array element) on compile time in Swift?
struct MyStruct {
    @ArrayOfNonOptionalElements var arr: [SomeNonOptionalType]
}

where @ArrayOfNonOptionalElements is a propertyWrapper.
So, how to force non-optionality for the type inside? Is it even possible? 
I mean, how to implement the property wrapper in such a way, that it forces the array element type to be non-optional.
Update:
Well, looks like nobody understood my question 
I want the compiler to prevent putting a question mark inside the square brackets 
Update2:
Will copy/paste here one of my comments from under the post, so everyone could easily see it:

I'm writing "@Compact" propertyWrapper for safe array decoding. So the
result will be guaranteed not to contain any nils. This property
wrapper can operate with any array types. So it's rather just a kind
of perfectionist challenge 


What does your property wrapper actually do? Are you simply trying to enforce that a property cannot be optional? You don't need a property wrapper for that. Or are you actually trying to create a property wrapper which does something useful, but cannot operate on optionals?

@DávidPásztor I'm writing "@Compact" propertyWrapper for safe array decoding. So the result will be guaranteed not to contain any nils. This property wrapper can operate with any array types. So it's rather just a kind of perfectionist challenge

if your array is defined as [SomeNonOptionalType] it already guaranteed to not have nils. To have nils it would be [SomeNonOptionalType?]. So what exactly are you trying to prevent.

I think OP wants to have the wrappedValue as [T] for a propertywrapper attached @ArrayOfNonOptionalElements var arr: [T?]. Not sure though because the question itself says otherwise, but their reply suggests that.

To make your question clearer, can you show an attempt, and describe how it doesn't work?

The post is updated ✅

There is no "opposite" type to Optional in swift so I don't think you can achieve this compile time validation.

@JoakimDanielson Looks like an idea for Swift Evolution Proposal

Are you trying to ensure a developer doesn't accidentally type [SomeNonOptionalType?] instead of [SomeNonOptionalType] by requiring the same developer to annotate the line with @ArrayOfNonOptionalElements ? Why? The compiler already helps you without any special wrapper. If the array is accidentally declared to allow optionals, then every array access will require code to handle an optional instead of a non-optional.

@HangarRash I've updated the post again. Please, take a look

Am I get right, that @Compact will contain non-nils even if encoded data have nils?

@Roman Your updates do not answer my questions. What perceived benefit do you expect to get by trying to make a developer add @ArrayOfNonOptionalElements to a line of code just incase the same developer accidentally adds a ? to the rest of the array declaration? As I said, the compiler already helps you without needing any annotation.

@Cy-4AH ✅ That's whole the point

@HangarRash Maybe you're right. Well... looks like it's impossible to do that anyways

@Cy-4AH Actually even more. It will also "filter out" any decoding errors. So a mistake in a single element of a decoding array will not make the whole your app crash anymore  The problematic element will be just skipped.

@Roman your recent questions seem to be XY problems. Instead of overly simplifying a real-world problem you're trying to solve, it would be worth actually asking a question about a real world problem in the form of a [mcve].  The question of "How do I decode a JSON array in a way that if a single element cannot be decoded, it doesn't fail the whole decoding, but simply skips that element" would be a completely different question than what you ended up asking, but seemingly the problem you're actually trying to solve.

@Dávid Pásztor "How do I decode a JSON array in a way that if a single element cannot be decoded, it doesn't fail the whole decoding, but simply skips that element" is not my question, is not a problem. I know how to do that. Actually I did it already and it works perfectly fine  The problem I'm trying to solve right now is exactly in what I've asked: "I want the compiler to prevent putting a question mark inside the square brackets"

I can't think of a way to do this, and it kind of makes sense that you can't. By analogy, it would be similar to having some func i<T>(_ value: T) -> T { value }, but limiting it so T arbitrary can't be Int. What harm would come if the constraint didn't exist? Generics are about constraining values by protocols, which in tern gives those generic values more power (because you have access to the protocol's requirements). If there's something that a non-optional can do that an optional can't, you should capture that in a protocol constraint.

You need write own macro instead of propertyWrapper.  To bad that yours question is closed and you have accepted that it's impossible. Idea is nice

@Cy-4AH I've finished my work and open-sourced it. So now everybody can use the result (or even contribute ). I hope you'll find it useful  https://gitlab.com/roman.kisliachenko/decodable-kit


So, how to force non-optionality for the type inside? Is it even possible? 

No. Swift does not have a way to express "not" in the type system. (There is a new ~Copyable coming, but it does not mean "not Copyable." It means "removes the implicit assumption of Copyable.")

I'm writing "@Compact" propertyWrapper for safe array decoding. So the result will be guaranteed not to contain any nils. This property wrapper can operate with any array types.

This isn't really accurate. Optionals are Decodable if their Wrapped is Decodable. So the following is valid:
try JSONDecoder().decode([Int?].self, from: Data("[1]".utf8)) // [Optional(1)]

This suggests your @Compact could still return an array of Optionals. And if it can return Optionals, it can return nil. The type system has to be able to prove at compile time that this is impossible, and from what you've described, it is possible, you just "promise" it won't happen. And the type system isn't letting you get away with that, as is its job.
But even if you could really promise what you're promising, the Swift type system has no way to express it.

Yeah, I think I found a nice compromise solution already. Instead of fighting the system, I will use it to gain even more functionality for my wrapper. I will just change the semantics a little bit by renaming from "@Compact" to "@Exemptify". And will not filter out "nils" in a case if a developer explicitly put "?" inside the "[]". It will only filter out decoding errors in this case. If there is no "?" inside the "[]" then "nils" become decoding errors by itself and would be filtered out automatically. Feels like very consistent behavior

I've finished my work and open-sourced it. I would be grateful if you could take a look. I hope you'll find it interesting  gitlab.com/roman.kisliachenko/decodable-kit

I'm personally not a real fan of property wrappers for these kinds of things. If it works for you, that's great, but I find them too fragile for complex systems. It's easy to throw away the errors, but it's hard to actually deal with them this way. I talk a little bit about that, along with how I prefer to do this, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-k_vipGhugQ&t=340
